# 502 bad gateway error with django , gonicorn in ubuntu server

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, server

i got these error 502 bad gateway

when cheched error.log i got
[image]

when i checked goicorn
[image]

the nginex services is run but after check i got this error
[image]

this is my code in nginx/site-avalable

```
upstream keepalive-upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    keepalive 64;
}

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name qhse-erp.com www.qhse-erp.com;
    
     location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_pass http://keepalive-upstream;
        proxy_redirect off;
    
    }
    }
```

i has starting goincorn manual as that until solve this problem then i will create service to start it:
[image]

the the number of TPC sockets on the system is
[image]

Comment: This is a wide pretty broad question but how are you starting gunicorn? It looks like you use systemctl, so please provide the output of `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`

Comment: hi @teewuane thanks for you comment , the output is "
Unit gunicorn.service could not be found." because i use manual starting for gunicorn ,i didn't create service for start gonicrn yet , i add photo to how do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATABASE_HOST must be "localhost" not the domain "www..com"

```
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

as this
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBPjV.png